# Character with byte sequence 0x9d in encoding 'WIN1252' has no equivalent in encoding 'UTF8'

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I am reading a csv file in my sql script and copying its data into a postgre sql table. The line of code is below :

```
\copy participants_2013 from 'C:/Users/Acrotrend/Desktop/mip_sahil/mip/reelportdata/Participating_Individual_Extract_Report_MIPJunior_2013_160414135957.Csv' with CSV delimiter ',' quote '"' HEADER;
```

I am getting following error : character with byte sequence 0x9d in encoding 'WIN1252' has no equivalent in encoding 'UTF8'.

Can anyone help me with what the cause of this issue and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The problem is that `0x9D` is not a valid byte value in WIN1252.
There's a table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

The problem may be that you are importing a UTF-8 file and postgresql is defaulting to Windows-1252 (which I believe is the default on many windows systems).

You need to change the character set on your windows command line before running the script with [chcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp).  Or in postgresql you can:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8';
```

Before importing the file.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to run the same command if you want to read the same data from psql tool.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları That's possible but not necessary.  The subtle difference is this question was interpreting the files as something different to their actual encoding.  What you're describing is when there are characters in the DB that don't exist in the default encoding for your shell.  The error seen when that happens are a little different.

Answer (score 6):

Simply specify `encoding 'UTF-8'` as the encoding in the `\copy` command, e.g. (I broke it into two lines for readability but keep it all on the same line):

```
\copy dest_table from 'C:/src-data.csv' 
                 (format csv, header true, delimiter ',', encoding 'UTF8');
```

More details:

The problem is that the Client Encoding is set to `WIN1252`, most likely because it is running on Windows machine but the file has a `UTF-8` character in it.

You can check the Client Encoding with

```
SHOW client_encoding;

 client_encoding
-----------------
WIN1252
```

Answer (score 1):

Any encoding has numeric ranges of valid code. Are you sure so your data are in win1252 encoding?

Postgres is very strict and doesn't import any possible encoding broken files. You can use `iconv` that can works in tolerant mode, and it can remove broken chars. After cleaning by `iconv` you can import the file.

Comment: I just checked the encoding of my file in notepad and it showed as 'UTF8'. So I don't understand why is it giving me the error of encoding issues.

Comment: maybe your postgresql client does switch to Win1252 encoding. What is result of "show client_encoding;"?

Comment: Run `\encoding UTF8` in `psql`.

Comment: I tried running \encoding UTF8 in psql but it is giving error as              'UTF8 :Invalid encoding name or conversion procedure not found

Comment: I know this is an old post but I just had this problem, and @Pavel Stehule solution worked for me. The command is actually `\encoding 'UTF8'`

Comment: A emoji caused this problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and it was because inside of a TEXT column I had fancy quotes that had been copy/pasted from an external source.

Comment: While this surely helps; any visual example (code example ?) of the copy/pasted stuff would help even better.