# How do I fix an encoding error in order to upload a 5GB text file using psql? (ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92)

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, psql

I am trying to upload a series of tables (.txt files) into a PostgreSQL database that runs on my Windows 10 desktop. I use psql upload the files. I have successfully uploaded a couple of tables but the largest one (5GB with over 20 million rows) is giving me trouble:

`databasename=# \copy table1 FROM 'C:\Users\tablename.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`
 `ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x9d in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"`
`CONTEXT:  COPY table1, line 581330`

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130110/character-with-byte-sequence-0x9d-in-encoding-win1252-has-no-equivalent-in-enc) which suggested I check the client encoding...

`databasename=# SHOW client_encoding;`
 `client_encoding`
 `-----------------`
 `WIN1252`
 `(1 row)`

and then change it, which I tried:

`databasename=# SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8';`
`SET`

I then try the same copy command again and get the following error:

`ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92`
`CONTEXT:  COPY table1, line 206051`

I've read a little about 0x92 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26330256/10448224). It sounds like there is a character in the file which cannot be encoded when I try and perform the \copy command.

Some background:

I was able to upload about 1 million rows into SQL Server 2019 (free version) using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. (I stopped the import because it was taking too long.) I was also able to view the file in R using `read.csv`. Not sure if any of this is helpful. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you know what these are really supposed to be?  IN 1252, 0x92 is apparently a curly single quote, while 0x9d is apparently nothing.  In 437, they seem to be  AE ligature, and a Yen symbol.

Comment: @jjanes I checked the line referenced in the first error in R. A row contains one column where some of the characters are as such: Â€Œâ€™Vâ€.